# Can anyone help me get my headphone jack to work?

Tags: sound, headphones

thanks for reading this.  I recently installed Xubuntu on this computer.  The normal speaker out in the back of the computer works fine, but the two headphone jacks on the front of the computer do not work at all (sound just continues to play out of the speakers, which continue to be connected to the audio-out in the back of the computer).

In the Volume Control app that's included with Xubuntu I went to the "Output Devices" tab and toggled through the three "ports" that are shown: Speakers(unavailable), Headphones(unplugged), and Line Out (plugged in).  Mind you that the speakers are actually plugged in, as well as the headphones (these in one of the headphone jacks on the front of the computer).  Changing the "port" has no effect; sound continues to play out of the speakers on either setting.

I ran sudo lshw and got this:

```
mattsff                     
    description: Low Profile Desktop Computer
    product: HP Compaq 6000 Pro SFF PC (NV469UT#ABA)
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    serial: MXL0341M7N
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=low-profile family=103C_53307F power-on_password=disabled sku=NV469UT#ABA uuid=FF404B3E-0759-DF11-BBDA-64061C7FD485
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 3048h
       vendor: Hewlett-Packard
       physical id: 0
       serial: MXL0341M7N
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Hewlett-Packard
          physical id: 1
          version: 786G2 v01.09
          date: 08/25/2009
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 4MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7600  @ 3.06GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 5
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7600  @ 3.06GHz
          slot: XU1 PROCESSOR
          size: 2762MHz
          capacity: 3066MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1066MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm pti dtherm cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=2
        *-cache:0 DISABLED
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 128KiB
             capacity: 128KiB
             capabilities: burst internal write-back data
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 3MiB
             capacity: 3MiB
             capabilities: burst internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 38
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: M378B5673FH0-CH9
             vendor: JEDEC ID:80 CE
             physical id: 0
             serial: EC196563
             slot: XMM1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: M378B5673FH0-CH9
             vendor: JEDEC ID:80 CE
             physical id: 1
             serial: EF681C78
             slot: XMM2
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: M378B5673FH0-CH9
             vendor: JEDEC ID:80 CE
             physical id: 2
             serial: 188CE397
             slot: XMM3
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: M378B5673FH0-CH9
             vendor: JEDEC ID:80 CE
             physical id: 3
             serial: 38C97563
             slot: XMM4
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-flash UNCLAIMED
          description: Flash Memory
          physical id: 39
          slot: System board or motherboard
          capacity: 4MiB
        *-bank UNCLAIMED
             description: Chip FLASH Non-volatile
             physical id: 0
             slot: SYSTEM ROM
             size: 4MiB
             width: 2 bits
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 03
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display:0
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:1230(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Display controller
             product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f0400000-f04fffff
        *-communication:0
             description: Communication controller
             product: 4 Series Chipset HECI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:30 memory:f0527100-f052710f
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 4 Series Chipset PT IDER Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.2
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide pm msi pci_native_mode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ata_generic latency=0
             resources: irq:18 ioport:1238(size=8) ioport:1260(size=4) ioport:1240(size=8) ioport:1264(size=4) ioport:1220(size=16)
        *-communication:1
             description: Serial controller
             product: 4 Series Chipset Serial KT Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.3
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm msi 16550 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=serial latency=0
             resources: irq:17 ioport:1248(size=8) memory:f0524000-f0524fff
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: enp0s25
             version: 02
             serial: d4:85:64:06:1c:7f
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             resources: irq:33 memory:f0500000-f051ffff memory:f0525000-f0525fff ioport:1100(size=32)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:20 ioport:1120(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-48-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard
                   vendor: Microsoft
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@3:1
                   version: 1.00
                   serial: 604827101621
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:21 ioport:1140(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-48-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:22 ioport:1160(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-48-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@5
                logical name: usb5
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:22 memory:f0526800-f0526bff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-48-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: Displaylink USB3.0 Display
                   vendor: DisplayLink
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@1:6
                   version: 51.20
                   serial: CE01360103349
                   capabilities: usb-2.10
                   configuration: driver=usbfs maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:32 memory:f0520000-f0523fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:28 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:f0600000-f06fffff ioport:f8000000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RT2790 Wireless 802.11n 1T/2R PCIe
                vendor: Ralink corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:20:00.0
                logical name: wls1
                version: 00
                serial: 20:68:9d:37:ce:d6
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic firmware=0.40 ip=192.168.7.93 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:16 memory:f0600000-f060ffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:29 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:f8200000-f83fffff ioport:f8400000(size=2097152)
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:20 ioport:1180(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-48-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@6
                logical name: usb6
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:5
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:21 ioport:11a0(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-48-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@7
                logical name: usb7
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
                   vendor: MOSART Semi.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@7:1
                   version: 81.13
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:6
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:22 ioport:11c0(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-48-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@8
                logical name: usb8
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:7
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:20 memory:f0526c00-f0526fff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-48-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: a2
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82801JD (ICH10D) LPC Interface Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:31 ioport:1250(size=8) ioport:1268(size=4) ioport:1258(size=8) ioport:126c(size=4) ioport:11e0(size=32) memory:f0526000-f05267ff
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 0
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0f13
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 aux
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0303
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0401
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=parport_pc
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device PNP0501
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=serial
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device IFX0102
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=tpm_tis
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 9
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:08
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: a
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:09
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: b
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: c
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: SPCC Solid State
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 9A0
             serial: AA000000000000002154
             size: 119GiB (128GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=a44f3d4f
           *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                version: FAT32
                serial: 18ce-4b2c
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 512MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
           *-volume:1
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                size: 118GiB
                capacity: 118GiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   logical name: /
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: dce8e4d5-8909-47f4-899f-7da9d12f10b6
                   size: 118GiB
                   capacity: 118GiB
                   capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2021-04-02 18:58:22 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2021-04-05 10:12:46 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2021-04-05 10:12:46 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: d
          logical name: scsi3
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST3250318AS
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: HP35
             serial: 9VY9CN14
             size: 232GiB (250GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=ae94d2af
           *-volume
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sdb2
                size: 232GiB
                capacity: 232GiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sdb5
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 2964c006-14bf-479a-a853-cfa0948bc42f
                   size: 232GiB
                   capacity: 232GiB
                   capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2021-04-02 19:28:02 filesystem=ext4 modified=2021-04-02 20:09:13 mounted=2021-04-02 19:45:46 state=clean
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: e
          logical name: scsi4
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD A  DH16AAL
             vendor: hp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: LHDJ
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

P.S.  Running `alsactl restore` did not resolve the problem.